# How to access PHP variables in JavaScript or jQuery rather than <?php echo $variable ?>

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

How do I access PHP variables in JavaScript or jQuery? Do I have to write

```
<?php echo $variable1 ?>
<?php echo $variable2 ?>
<?php echo $variable3 ?>
...
<?php echo $variablen ?>
```

I know I can store some variables in cookies, and access these values via cookies, but values in cookies are relatively stable values. Moreover, there is a limit, you can not store many values in cookies, and the method is not that convenient. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: if you are going to mark things as 'dups' post links to those threads, otherwise its just postcount ++.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Your example shows the most simple way of passing PHP variables to JavaScript. You can also use json_encode for more complex things like arrays:

```
<?php
    $simple = 'simple string';
    $complex = array('more', 'complex', 'object', array('foo', 'bar'));
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var simple = '<?php echo $simple; ?>';
    var complex = <?php echo json_encode($complex); ?>;
</script>
```

Other than that, if you really want to "interact" between PHP and JavaScript you should use Ajax.

Using cookies for this is a very unsafe and unreliable way, as they are stored clientside and therefore open for any manipulation or won't even get accepted/saved. Don't use them for this type of interaction.
[jQuery.ajax](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) is a good start IMHO.

Comment: +1 for mentioning JSON with example.

Comment: You have quotes round `<?php echo $simple; ?>` and I think that's right. But you have quotes round `<?php echo json_encode($complex); ?>` as well, and I think that's wrong --- `json_encode()` returns valid javascript, so you don't want to quote it, surely?

Comment: Interaction between Javascript and PHP on the same PHP file, not on different PHP files.

Comment: There is no PHP/JavaScript interaction in just one file. For one file, there is only one-way PHP -> JavaScript.

Comment: Anything unclear then? My answer contains just that :)

Comment: aha, but it cannot be called in  js files with .js extensions(

Comment: json method looks really good.

Comment: The "simple" method of `var simple = '<?php echo $simple; ?>';` breaks if `$simple` contains unescaped apostrophes.

Answer (score 6):

If AJAX isn't an option you can use nested data structures to simplify.

```
<?php
$var = array(
    'qwe' => 'asd',
    'asd' => array(
        1 => 2,
        3 => 4,
    ),
    'zxc' => 0,
);
?>
<script>var data = <?php echo json_encode($var); ?>;</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're asking kind of a two-part question. As far as syntax (I think since PHP4?) you can use:

```
<?=$var?>
```

... if PHP is configured to allow it. And it is on most servers.

As far as storing user data, you also have the option of storing it in the session:

```
$_SESSION['bla'] = "so-and-so";
```

for persistence from page to page. You could also of course use a database. You can even have PHP store the session variables in the db. It just depends on what you need.

Comment: As you say, this syntax is configured on *most* servers, but not all.  For truly portable code, I'd still recommend using the full <?php echo $variable /? syntax.  It's only 7 characters more per instance. However, if you have full control over your hosting servers, and you know you are not going to make the code available for other users on different servers, then go for it.

Comment: you don't have access to $_SESSION inside javascript

Comment: @Karsten: I wasn't suggesting that you do. I was just suggesting using session variables instead of cookies, when cookies aren't necessary. You would still have to echo them inside your script, of course.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue when building a custom pagination for a site I am working on.

The global variable I created in functions.php was defined and set to 0. I could output this value in my javascript no problem using the method @Karsten outlined above. The issue was with updating the global variable that I initially set to 0 inside the PHP file.

Here is my workaround (hacky? I know!) but after struggling for an hour on a tight deadline the following works:

**Inside archive-episodes.php:**

```
<script>
    // We define the variable and update it in a php
    // function defined in functions.php
    var totalPageCount; 
</script>
```

**Inside functions.php**

```
<?php
    $totalPageCount = WP_Query->max_num_pages; // In my testing scenario this number is 8.
    echo '<script>totalPageCount = $totalPageCount;</script>';
?>
```

To keep it simple, I was outputting the *totalPageCount* variable in an **$ajax.success** callback via alert.

```
$.ajax({
        url: ajaxurl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: {"action": "infinite_scroll", "page_no": pageNumber, "posts_per_page": numResults},
        beforeSend: function() {
            $(".ajaxLoading").show();
        },
        success: function(data) {
                            //alert("DONE LOADING EPISODES");
            $(".ajaxLoading").hide();

            var $container = $("#episode-container");

            if(firstRun) {
                $container.prepend(data);
                initMasonry($container);
                ieMasonryFix();
                initSearch();
            } else {
                var $newItems = $(data);
                $container.append( $newItems ).isotope( 'appended', $newItems );
            }
            firstRun = false;

            addHoverState();                            
            smartResize();

            alert(totalEpiPageCount); // THIS OUTPUTS THE CORRECT PAGE TOTAL
        }
```

Be it as it may, I hope this helps others! If anyone has a "less-hacky" version or best-practise example I'm all ears.

Comment: Please, do rate other users when they make good constructives answers, doesnt matter if they are old or fresh. We are responsible to provide positive feedback on the ones who make a good effort. Even if this didnt help you just voting up means you find this helpful (not always to you)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, yes. You write `alert('<?php echo($phpvariable); ?>');`

There are sure other ways to interoperate, but none of which i can think of being as simple (or better) as the above.

Comment: There are two questions in the question, which are you answering?

Comment: Two questions? Only one question.

Answer (score 0):

I would say echo() ing them directly into the Javascript source code is the most reliable and downward compatible way. Stay with that unless you have a good reason not to.

Comment: This is a poor answer. It does not utilize and example. Yes, using imbedded PHP to echo a value into a script is a common concept. However, since the user is asking, we can presume that they don't know. Your answer would just be frustrating. It is as un-helpful as some those that say such things as "Yes, I think you can do that", or "It should not be hard". Not trying to be too critical. Just saying we should keep our answers very clear, and provide required details.

Comment: @Don Then write a better answer, or refer to the others given that come with plenty of examples. This topic is 3 years old, and has a highly upvoted accepted answer. I don't think there is anything to do here