# Is there a way to include PHP value inside a javascript function?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to dynamically tell a javascript which `<div>` to hide, but I dont know how to send the request to the javascript as it is a client side script.

for eg:

```
<?
$divtohide = "adiv";
?>
<script language="javascript">
            function hidediv($divtohide) {
            ................
            }
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP/Javascript - get php variable within javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787978/php-javascript-get-php-variable-within-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `$divtohide` actually contains the ID of a `<div>` element and not a JavaScript variable name, write your JavaScript function as normal:

```
function hidediv(divtohide) {
    // Your code may differ here, mine's just for example
    document.getElementById(divtohide).style.display = 'none';
}
```

And print out the PHP variable only when you're calling it, within a pair of quotes:

```
hidediv("<?php echo addslashes($divtohide); ?>");
```

[`addslashes()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) ensures that quotes `"` in the variable are escaped so your JavaScript doesn't break.

Answer (score 0):

as BoltClock wrote, use `php` to pass the variable.

but you can do it by most simple way, just write `hidediv("<?=$divtohide?>")`

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function hidediv() {

    divobj = document.getElementById('<?= $divtohide ?>');

    divobj.style.display = 'none';

}

</script>
```

Comment: why did i get -1? My code does exactly what he wants. grumble grumble