# Access PHP variable in JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access PHP variables in JavaScript or jQuery rather than <?php echo $variable ?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808108/how-to-access-php-variables-in-javascript-or-jquery-rather-than-php-echo-vari)

Is there any way to get access to a PHP variable in JavaScript?

I have a variable, `$a`, in PHP and want to get its value in a JavaScript variable.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You can't, you'll have to do something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var php_var = "<?php echo $php_var; ?>";
</script>
```

You can also load it with AJAX

rhino is right, the snippet lacks of a type for the sake of brevity.

Also, note that if `$php_var` has quotes, it will break your script. You shall use addslashes, htmlentities or a custom function.

Comment: rhino is correct, json_encode escapes the variable.

Comment: W3C states that `The type attribute must be specified for each SCRIPT element instance in a document.`

Comment: Right, he was probably just omitting it for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @stillstanding: Be specific: W3C states where? It's not required in HTML5.

Comment: See for yourself: `The **required** type attribute specifies the MIME type of the script.` http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tag_script.asp

Comment: @stillstanding: I wouldn't trust W3Schools as much as the actual spec. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html#script -- The type attribute gives the language of the script or format of the data. ... The default, which is used if the attribute is absent, is "text/javascript".

Comment: Interesting.  Here's the tag specification.  Nowhere that I can see does it mention that type is required.  Time to update my brain to HTML5.  http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/script.html

Comment: json_encode() escapes quotes.

Comment: But this does not work in case of an array, e.g. if there is an array `$vars` in php, using `
var k="<?php print_r($vars);?>";` in JavaScript does not work.

Answer (score 51):

metrobalderas is partially right. Partially, because the PHP variable's value may contain some special characters, which are metacharacters in JavaScript. To avoid such problem, use the code below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var something=<?php echo json_encode($a); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: +1.  Tested, and json_encode _does_ quote and escape strings properly.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how necessary this is, and it adds a call to `getElementById`, but if you're really keen on getting inline JavaScript out of your code, you can pass it as an HTML attribute, namely:

```
<span class="metadata" id="metadata-size-of-widget" title="<?php echo json_encode($size_of_widget) ?>"></span>
```

And then in your JavaScript:

```
var size_of_widget = document.getElementById("metadata-size-of-widget").title;
```

Comment: Though I'm 12 years late, though, people if you should not use this as the user can simply edit the value passed by php to js