# Php pass array to Javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I want an **array in Javascript**, structure like this

```
        $(function()
    {
        // prepare the data
        for (var i=0; i<50000; i++) {
            var d = (data[i] = {});

            d["id"] = "id_" + i;
            d["num"] = i;
            d["title"] = "Task " + i;
            d["duration"] = "5 days";
        }
```

I want this array **to be created through php.**
I already have the array there created by for loop

***EDITED:***

Is the above data in Javascript a multidimensional array, a simple array or a var?

is the structure saved in "d" or in data[i][id],data[i][title],... ?

Comment: And please mark the best answer to your question here.

Comment: sorry now i will. i did not know so far, thx 4the hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ie, $data = array('item' => 'description', 'item2' => 'description2');

json_encode($data);

All you need

Comment: Dumping an array of 50,000 elements onto the page is hardly ideal, but without more info I don't see a better solution.

Comment: I don't think putting 50,000 of anything onto one page using _any_ method is ideal.

Answer (score 2):

Use json_encode() to encode the array.

[Access PHP variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript/4287399#4287399)
That example works with arrays, too.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you. What do you mean by saying "it's quicker"?

Comment: Linking to your answer, instead of writing it again. :)  </offtopic>

Comment: could you give an example in php how the structure of the array has to look to fit into the Javascript. The javascript part as i understood your answer is simply echoing var d=<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;

Comment: Any array, string, or integer can be passed through.  Json_encode takes care of the rest.