# How to pass JavaScript variable to <img> in php

Tags: javascript, php, function

I want to pass javascript variable as a path to `<img src="path">` in php 
 my code is 
 javascript code

```
    function showSmallImage(path)
    {
        document.getElementById("small_image").value = path;
    }
```

i am getting path and i have to pass it to 
 php code

```
echo "<img id='small_image' src='".$path."'>";
```

but i am not getting any way to solve it please suggest me any way to solve this issue. 
Thanks in advanced!!!

Comment: Well you are aware that javascript is client side code and it's variables / values are in the clients browser. PHP is done server side and doesn't have any access to this kind of stuff.

Comment: OK I'm confused - do you want to take a path you have in PHP and echo it on the page or do you want to take the path from an existing <img> and pass that along to PHP?

Comment: i have two product image thumbnail and small and path of both images is stored in database. now on click of thumbnail image i want to show small image in a div

Comment: so i create a javascript function and call it onclick of thumbnail image and passed path of small image so i am getting that path of small image in function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Value is not any attribute for image tag and if you want to chnage the sorce if image then use given code

```
function showSmallImage(path)
    {
        $("#small_image").prop('src',path);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your HTML file in the [head] section:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var path = "<?php echo $path_from_php; ?>";
</script>
```

I stole this from [another stack answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript).  @Subhash posted the other half (javascript side).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any JavaScript here. Have something like this:

```
echo "<a href='".$big_path."'><img src='".$small_path."' /></a>";
```

Where `small_path` is the PHP variable with the small image path and `big_path` hold the path to big/full image.

This will give you the small image that when clicked, will show the big image.