# Use PHP variables in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi i have read this thread about using php variable in jquery but somehow it doesnt work on my site:
[LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript/)

Javascript:

```
<script>
var row_id="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>";

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#que"+row_id).click(function(){
    $("#ans"+row_id).slideToggle();
  });
});


</script>
<?php foreach($res as $r) : ?>

    <li id="que<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">Q<?php echo $r['id']; ?>: <?php echo $r['question']; ?>          </li> 
    <div id="ans<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" style="padding:5px;">A: <?php echo $r['answer']; ?></div> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a very good description of the problem, what exactly doesn't work, did you check the console for errors etc

Comment: what is the generated HTML you are getting ?

Comment: replace `?> ?>` with `?>` in your js

Comment: As a sidenote, you do understand that the variables inside the loop are not available outside the loop, as you seem to think you can use those PHP variables anywhere ?

Comment: I am trying to make a FAQs section, that when people click the "question" the answer will slide down, with jquery toggle.

Comment: *the ?>?> typed above is a typo **

Answer (score 7):

Just use classes. Otherwise you will end up having a jquery piece of code for each question.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".que").click(function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>

<?php foreach($res as $r) : ?>
    <li class="que">Q<?php echo $r['id']; ?>: <?php echo $r['question']; ?></li> 
    <div style="padding:5px;">A: <?php echo $r['answer']; ?></div> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YwS2x/)**

Comment: holy crap you and i had the exact same answer I was not expecting that haha (not a hard one to figure out but some of these answers tonight have made me question the S.O. crowd lol)

Comment: I hope we are not twins lol :D

Comment: why that would be freakin awesome hahaha

Comment: Well because i already have one http://stackoverflow.com/users/860103/aamir-adnan :D Otherwise it will be a trio :D

Comment: My goodness yes that would be crazy.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`Script` tag should be inside the `forach` loop.

Please try this and explain exact what error you got?

Comment: So you want his jQuery printed multiple times throughout the page?

Comment: Never try to use such type of script in loop.

Answer (score 0):

you wouldn't get this value `var row_id="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>";` because `$r['id']` is in the `foreach`.

I assume that you want to take the `$r['id']`, so try something like this

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".row").click(function(){
            var row_id = $(this).val();
            $("#ans"+row_id).slideToggle();
        });
    });

</script>

<?php foreach($res as $r) : ?>

    <li id="que<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">Q<?php echo $r['id']; ?>: <?php echo $r['question']; ?></li>
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="row" />
    <div id="ans<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" style="padding:5px;">A: <?php echo $r['answer']; ?></div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes and `.next()` to solve this easily:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.que').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.ans').slideToggle();
  });
});


</script>
<?php foreach($res as $r) : ?>
    <li id="que<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="que">Q<?php echo $r['id']; ?>: <?php echo $r['question']; ?>          </li> 
    <div id="ans<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" class="ans" style="padding:5px;">A: <?php echo $r['answer']; ?></div> 
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have used the undefined variable $r in javascript.

Which is only defined in the foreach loop. get the javascript into the loop it will work.

```php
<script>
    function q_click(row_id){
        $("#ans"+row_id).slideToggle();
    }
 </script>
    <?php foreach($res as $r) : ?>

        <li id="que<?php echo $r['id']; ?>">Q<?php echo $r['id']; ?>: <?php echo $r['question']; ? onclick="q_click(<?php echo $r['id']; ?>)">          </li> 
        <div id="ans<?php echo $r['id']; ?>" style="padding:5px;">A: <?php echo $r['answer']; ?></div> 
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I can't see `$r` anywhere in the javascript context in the asker's code.

Comment: $r is as PHP variable which is used in javascript

Comment: Concerning your code - I don't think it's a good idea to use a separate `$(document).ready(...)` call for each row in the table. Perhaps you should loop twice instead? (or just see [@Khawer's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20878440/499214))

Comment: @JanDvorak any relation to John C. Dvorak? lol and for the author of this answer: This is very wasteful and inefficient code.  Please reconsider

Comment: This is not best to use but it should work. @khawer gives the best solution for this.

Comment: @JanDvorak I have edited my answer and now it should work efficiently.