# Check if user Logged in

Tags: javascript, php

hey There I completely new to this kind of work! Actually I want to check if user is successfully logged in!

suppose that i have a menu item:

```
  <li><a href="#" title="Know about Java" onclick="CheckSignIn()">Java</a></li>
```

when user clicks on it:

```
function CheckSignIn() {
    //here i want to check login

    if (!login) {
        alert('please login');
    } else {
        window.open('new page url here');
    }
}
```

I know how can i do it with php i.e.

```
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
    echo (welcome user);//sort of                           
} else {
    echo "please login!";           
}
?>
```

In simple I want to check if user logs in using javascript and i know i cant use php inside java script can somebody help me please! Its not an assignment but i am learning it to my own

Comment: You need to understand the difference between server-side code and client-side code.  What you're asking for is not secure.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve is for educational purpose, but seriously, never use it anywhere.

Comment: Keep in mind; JavaScript is never secure. No matter how obfuscated or hidden functions are, if they're run client-side, they can be manipulated. Checking authentication (logging in) should **always** be done server-side. If you want to show client-side that they are logged in, either let the server give the client a page with that message or load it asynchronous using AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You cannot check session variable using JavaScript since a session variable is stored on server. To do this you'll have to call your server side code asynchronously using js. jQuery ajax can help you make the async call.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to [access-php-variable-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript)

Even $_SESSION is a PHP variable so I am sure you should be able to get it in javascript variable.

Comment: you can use a localstorage.setItem. That is a dataset. Notice that you only can store a string in it.

for example:
localstorage.setItem('loggedIn', 'false');

Answer (score 0):

One way is to send a xhr to the server which returns true or false if a user is signed in (aka a session value is set eventually making a database call), parse the response and return true or false.

Another way is to send an encrypted token (jwt is what I use currently) upon login that is stored in the browser's sessionStorage

So either you have everything on the server side
or you have the clientside UI which makes requests to the server side api.

Both have advantages and disadvantages.

If you have a client side UI that makes requests to an api, like in your example I suggest you send a JWT upon login, store it in the browser's sessionStorage.
Now you'd like to check on the client side if a user is logged in for display purposes. So check if a token in the sessionStorage exists, that means a user is logged in. Now when making a request to the server you send that token in a header field. The server checks the token for validity and if valid performs the operation. If not status 403.

This has downsides, the user needs to log in for every browser window it opens. Storing it in localStorage adds new security considerations, which are out of scope of the question (CSP, X-Frame-Options, and so on). JWT by default uses RSA and SHA256 (RS256).

The flow is:

1. User fills out login form and hits submit
2. Server receives the login information and if valid sends a token
3. If reponse status != 403|401 store the token in sessionStorage
4. When making a request to a protected resource the client sends the token in a header field.
5. Server checks token for validity
6. If valid send protected resource (or content that was requested)
7. Client renders received content

Comment: but then how can i allow my users to only access a link if they are members!

Comment: you perform the validation on the server side. let's say `GET /api/v1/protected_resources/123` your browser sends the token in the header. The handler (let's call it protected.php) reads the token from the header. If valid it returns the protected content if not it does nothing or sends a 403 (forbidden). Let's assume it's valid your browser renders the content of the response in the template. Let's assume user1 is allowed to view the resource, the token has the info `user:user1` on the server side you check the acl "does user1 have access to protected1" if true send protected1

Comment: since you're not making a difference between user's access levels you don't need to query the acl. If token valid return protected resource