# How to get a string from external PHP file and set it as var in JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, html

I thought this would be simple enough, but I can't get it to work.

I have two files. `main.html` and `data.php`
The two files are in the same folder on a server.

I want to get a string from the `PHP` file and use it in jQuery. In the example below, I want the browser to create a pop-up, with the text "xxxx". I get no pop-up.

### `data.php`

```
<?php

$var = "xxxx";

echo json_encode($var);

?>
```

### `main.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>      
        <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var testString = <?php $var = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.php'), true); echo $var; ?>;
                alert(testString);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any takers?

Comment: your php ini not recognize .html file for php code change it to html.php and use include once data.php at the top of main.php. And learn more about php and how it works. $.ajax if you use jquery.

Comment: why you are not use Ajax for this

Comment: @gvgvgvijayan my php ini? Are you saying I should change the extension of data.php to html?

Comment: @ShailendraSharma I might try Ajax after I can get this to work.

Comment: if you want to run your php code on html page than create a .htaccess file and put "AddType application/x-httpd-php .html .htm" on it so you can run php code on the html file

Comment: change main.html to main.php and at the top use `include_once('data.php');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"data.php",
                    success:function(result){
                        alert(result);
                    }
                });             
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem with this is that on many servers .html is not parsed for PHP

The second problem is that the `file_get_contents` will actually display the full contents of your .php file (including the `<?php`) which is likely not what you're looking for.

Instead I would use an AJAX request such as http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

For this you will need to include jQuery in your `<head>`

Comment: I'll give AJAX a try and get back to you (I am using jQuery in my main project).

Comment: make sure that your *data.php* file is in the same level as *main.php*

Answer (score 0):

You should get the php data before html initiates, like below

```
<?php
$var = json_decode(file_get_contents('data.php'), true);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
    <head>      
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var testString = <?php echo $var; ?>;
                alert(testString);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, the double quotes makes the alert that exact string, and not the PHP contents.

Comment: check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript