# How to get visible div inputs in a page through php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to get the names of the visible div inputs there are two visible..!
but it's getting difficult for me..I got a way out with javascript but I really want to to do it in PHP..! as names of divs and inputs are changing on every visit and reloading the page..! so it's quite difficult to target by any permanent name or ID..!

Here is how I got it from a user in javascript :

```
var isCandidateRegion=function(node){
return (node.innerText.indexOf('Username')>-1 && node.innerText.indexOf('Hours')>-1);
};
//Find the last table in th document that contains 'Username' and 'Hours'
var candidateRegions=[].filter.call(document.querySelectorAll('table'),isCandidateRegion);
var targetRegion=candidateRegions[candidateRegions.length-1];

var isVisible=function(node){
return (node.offsetWidth && node.offSetWidth >0) || (node.offsetHeight && node.offsetHeight>0);
};
var inputs=[].filter.call(targetRegion.querySelectorAll('input'),isVisible);
var usernameInput=inputs[0].name;
var hoursInput=inputs[1].name;

console.log(usernameInput,hoursInput);
```

So what I want is to get the names in a php variable so that I can use it in php now..I can see the names of the inputs in console but I want it to store in a PHP variable..!

So if there is any way please or alternative of using jQuery or Javascript as PHP will be great..!

Comment: php is a server side script it will process before your page loads.

Comment: yeah...ofcourse..so any luck how can I make this working someway?

Comment: how can you get php variables in Javascript??

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava you can always get php variable in javascript but the opposite is not possible.

Comment: can you show some example??...Have a look to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript

Comment: <?php $arr=10;?>
<script type="text/javascript">

var x=<?php echo $arr;?>;
alert(x);
</script>   try this.

Comment: @user4089052 i don't know your use but may be try ajax to pass these values to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is a server side language which for all intents and purposes relating to how I understand your question, is basically there only to serve and read HTML code. Unless you have something actually written on a DOM element, there is no way for PHP to know whether it is visible or not, as it can't automatically detect its styling like JavaScript can.

JavaScript on the other hand is designed for working with DOM page elements and detecting styles, or manipulating elements.

To make your PHP see what elements are visible, you need to explicitly tell PHP what is and isn't visible by putting it into HTML using JavaScript (or jQuery). This can be done by:

- Adding a specific class onto your `div` that you want to make known to PHP e.g. `<div class="visible"> ... </div>` or `<div class="hidden"> ... </div>`.
- Adding a data attribute to your element e.g. `<div data-visibility="visible"> ... </div>` or `<div data-visibility="hidden"> ... </div>`

In your PHP, on the method reading info from the page you can traverse the DOM and get all `div`'s that have the appropriate class or attribute.