# How to get value from php inside a javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

In the below script default values are used. I would like to use values from database like `<?php $user->location ?>` i.e., I want to use users loaction data inside `var states`.

How do I do it?

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California'
  ];
</script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access PHP variable in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: Either ajax or var states = <? echo json_encode($array); ?>;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
    $ar = array('one', 'two', 1, false, null, true, 2 + 5);
 ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var ar = <?php echo json_encode($ar) ?>;
  // ["one","two",1,false,null,true,7];
  // access 4th element in array
  alert( ar[3] ); // false
</script>
```

Thank You!!

Answer (score 2):

Do like this

```
 <script>
     var test = "<?php json_encode($variable); ?>";
 </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In Yii you can use [registerJS](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJs%28%29-detail) in your view file:

```
<?php
    $js = "var states = ['" . 
          implode("','", ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California']) .
          "'];";
    $this->registerJs($js, View::POS_BEGIN)

    // Now states is globally available in JS
?>
<div> ... your view html ... </div>
```

You can also add this JS code within a controller action instead of placing it into the view file:

```
public function actionIndex() {
    $js = "var states = ['" . 
          implode("','", ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California']) .
          "'];";

    $this->view->registerJs($js, View::POS_BEGIN);
    return $this->render('index', []);
}
```

Of course you can replace the array with any array you want. You could use e.g.:

```
$states = States::find()->column();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var states = <?php echo json_encode($user->location); ?>;
});
</script>
```