# How to make my bar charts dynamic

Tags: javascript, php, charts, bar-chart

i want to represent the following array data which is stored in the variable $dataBycountry.
this variable contain

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [country] => Russia
            [sessions] => 132
            [users] => 3
            [pageviews] => 261
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [country] => India
            [sessions] => 31
            [users] => 20
            [pageviews] => 67
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [country] => Austria
            [sessions] => 18
            [users] => 18
            [pageviews] => 53
        )
)
```

and this is my script

```
var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};

var barChartData = {
    labels : ["i want lables also to be dynamic"],
    datasets : [
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
            highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
            highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        },
        {
            fillColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
            strokeColor : "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
            highlightFill : "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
            highlightStroke : "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
            data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor()]
        }
    ]

}
window.onload = function(){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    window.myBar = new Chart(ctx).Bar(barChartData, {
        responsive : true
    });
}
```

i want to use those countries as lables and display barcharts dynamically.please give me a solution how to use that $dataByCountry variable in script.

Comment: Is that PHP at the beginning there? Question isn't tagged PHP, but that is definitely not valid JavaScript.

Comment: yes there is php code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been covered before... The following link should help. It outlines several different approaches along with their pros and cons.

[How to pass variables and data from PHP to JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23740548/how-to-pass-variables-and-data-from-php-to-javascript)

Several other duplicates:

[Access PHP variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript)

[How to access PHP variables in JavaScript or jQuery rather than <?php echo $variable ?>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808108/how-to-access-php-variables-in-javascript-or-jquery-rather-than-php-echo-vari)