# Double quote single quote not working in PHP/JavaScript

Tags: html

I can't get my required result when i use this code

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$returnMessage = "Hey"; 
$test = fopen('check.txt', a+);
fwrite($test, '
   if (empty($_SESSION["nabeel"])) {
     echo "<script>alert($returnMessage)</script>";
   };
    ?>    ')
```

I also tried doing this but does work...

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$returnMessage = "Hey"; 
?>
$test = fopen('check.txt', a+);
fwrite($test, '
   if (empty($_SESSION["nabeel"])) {
     echo "<script>alert(<?php $returnMessage ?>)</script>";
   }
    ?>    ')
```

I think I have some problem with quotes.

Comment: What's the required result? What result are you getting?

Comment: Do you realise that `$test = ` and `fwrite` are not within PHP tags so are just being output to the browser? Perhaps you should read a few PHP tutorials before trying to actually use a language you don't yet know. You also need to use `;` at the end of each PHP statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
$returnMessage = "Hey";
$test = fopen('check.txt', a+);
if (empty($_SESSION["nabeel"]))
    fwrite($test,'<script>alert('. $returnMessage .');</script>');
?>
```

Comment: BUT this won't make it alert???

Comment: @CLEO MASTER i have update.try...

Comment: ok can i ask you a simple question. How can i use a php string variable in the fwrite area and add that variable in the alert box. How would i do that please give me a code. Thanks by the way!!

Comment: I did not understand your question.if you want to use a php variable in a script javascript see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript. Or use an <input type="hidden" value="<?php...?>" name"..."/>