# Sending a PHP session variable to javascript of another file

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I extracted data from a CSV file using PHP and stored the data as a nested array.
I stored this array as a session variable and now I want to access the array in another html file using javascript. How can this be done?

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $arr=array();

    $arr['1']=array('abc','def');
    $arr['2']=array('123','456');

    $_SESSION["abc"]=$arr;

?>
```

This is a sample php. I have to access the session variable in javascript.

Comment: post relevant code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access PHP variable in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287357/access-php-variable-in-javascript)

Comment: Put in to an input? Store it as a cookie? Make use of AJAX? `echo` (output) it?

Comment: Refer to [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: var mgmt='<?php echo $_SESSION[\'MUMMGMT\']; ?>'. Many posts told to do it this way. It is not working

Comment: Cuz you cant echo array like this :D :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should be aware of, is that php is server side and javascript is client side. So to solve this, you have 2 options:

1. let the php code add this variables in the head. on to of everything:

   ```
   <script>
     var php_variables= <?php echo json_encode($your_php_variables); ?>;
   </script>
   ```

or 2. Make a seperate php file which just echos only the value in json and put a json header:

```
 <?php 
  header("content-type:application/json");
  echo json_encode($your_php_variables);
 ?>
```

and then let javascript retrieve it. there are many libraries available for that. but lets take a comon one like jquery:

```
$.get("yourphpfile.php",function(data){do something here})
```

Comment: Your first method helped in retrieving the array into javascript. I confirmed it by doing console.log(). But doing document.write of the variable is giving [object Object]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use implode PHP function to convert your array to string and then `echo` that string and assign to a JS variable like in example below.

Your another HTML file:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $your_array=$_SESSION['your_array'];
?>
<script>
    var js_variable = [<?php echo implode($your_array,','); ?>];
    console.log(js_variable);
</script>
```