# Javascript: Can't delete after the Confirmation Message

Tags: javascript, php

Here's my scenario:

I have a form, main_play.php, where its a list of all playlist then when I click the radio button it will pop up a confirmation message then after that it will proceed to the form of play_delete...Proceeding in the next page is working...

But in the play_delete.php all variables there are already empty... But, when I'm not using the confirmation message it can be deleted and also the variables are transferred in play_delete...

Here's my variable:

```
$get_ID = $_POST['deletePlaylist'];
```

Here's my code for PHP:

```
<input type="radio" name="deletePlaylist[]" class="chk_boxes1" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"<?php echo ($_POST['deletePlaylist[]'] == $row['id'] ? 'checked=" checked"' : ''); ?> onclick='confirmation()'>
```

Here's my javascript:

```
<script>
function confirmation() {
    var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")
    if (answer){

        window.location = 'play_delete.php';
    }
    else{
        alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
    }
}
</script>
```

Is there a way to transfer the data in php to javascript then javascript to the next page??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are just relocating, you could make your list a form and just submit that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
  window.location = 'play_delete.php';
```

with

```
 document.formname.action = 'play_delete.php';
 document.formname.submit();
```

where **formname** is the name of the form on the page in which all the playlist radio buttons are appearing.

Answer (score 1):

try this it will work

```
<script>
    function confirmation(value) {
        var answer = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?")
        if (answer){

            window.location = 'play_delete.php?data='+value;
        }
        else{
            alert("Thanks for sticking around!")
        }
    }
    </script>

    <body>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="uniqvalue" id="name" onclick='confirmation(this.value);'/>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this for transferring a PHP variable to a javascript variable:

[How to access PHP variables in JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808108/how-to-access-php-variables-in-javascript-or-jquery-rather-than-php-echo-vari)