# PHP array to JSON - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have a php nested array stored in a variable `$myArray`, below is how the array looks like (its not a complete output) after var dumping it to the browser.

```
<?php var_dump($myArray); ?>
```

The output:

```
array (size=4)
  'id' => string '162' (length=3)
  'content' => string 'Test content' (length=12)
  'children' => 
    array (size=16)
      0 => 
        array (size=4)
          'id' => string '29208' (length=5)
          'content' => string 'Test content 1' (length=14)
          'children' => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
      1 => 
        array (size=4)
          'id' => string '29215' (length=5)
          'content' => string 'Test content 2' (length=14)
          'children' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      2 => 
        array (size=3)
          'id' => string '29220' (length=5)
          'content' => string 'Test Content 3' (length=14)
```

Reading the variable array from JavaScript as below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar = JSON.parse('<?php json_encode($myArray) ?>');
</script>
```

Returns the following error in the console

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

**While debugging the code, I did the following:**

Created a new variable and stored some JSON data in it and then JSON parsed it to another variable and then finally consoled the output and it worked fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = '{"id":123,"content":"This is a test content"}';
var myVar = JSON.parse(x);
console.log(myVar); 
</script>
```

The output was an object with those values in the console:

```
Object
    content: "This is a test content"
    id: 123
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why json encode and then parse in JS? Why not print as-is? Like: `var myVar = <?= json_encode($myArray) ?>;`

Comment: Rudie is correct, you do not need to parse the JSON as a string when outputting it directly to the browser in this way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to access PHP variables in JavaScript or jQuery rather than <?php echo $variable ?>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808108/how-to-access-php-variables-in-javascript-or-jquery-rather-than-php-echo-vari)

Comment: This question is answered in that question where you should've looked. He clearly shows how to use an object instead of a string and states that quotes will break the script.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`var myVar = <?php echo json_encode($myArray) ?>;`
should do it. No `'` characters are needed because the JSON object can be read as written, and  no parse is necessary because it's outputting directly onto the page instead of giving it a string

Answer (score 4):

You need to echo out the json object.

```
<?php json_encode($myArray) ?>
```

to

```
<?php echo json_encode($myArray) ?>
```

Comment: No, `JSON.parse` parses a string into a javascript object. If you take out the single quotes you're converting a Javascript Object to a Javascript Object. Essentially in this form, you don't even need the `JSON.parse`, you could set the variable directly from the `json_encode`. i.e. `var obj = <?php echo json_encode($myArray); ?>;`

Comment: I tried `var myVar = '<?php echo json_encode($notes); ?>';` and `var myVar = '<?= json_encode($notes) ?>';` both return `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a little shorthand trick for you explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020445/what-does-mean-in-php)

You can simply do `<?=$var?>`. It's basically shorthand for `echo` and only works if the shorthand tag `<?` is enabled.

So the answer to your question (if shorthand open tags are enabled) you can use this

`var myVar = <?=json_encode($myArray)?>;`
Which is equivalent to what @Dar gave you above but less ugly.