# Why php variable cant work with javascript loop?

Tags: javascript, php

I expected that the number will increase on every alert, but it ended up being the same number which is 0.

Can I know why ?

I need to do this because in my real code, $wow represent the value I retrieved from server and I need to use javascript for loop to count the number element which I targeted.

How can i do this ?

Here is my Code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
<?php $wow = 0; ?>
for(var i =0; i < 4; i++){
   alert("<?php echo $wow; ?>");
    <?php $wow++; ?>
    }
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is executed on the server side, JavaScript on the client side. The way it works is like this: browser makes request `->` server receives request `->` server executes PHP `->` server sends response/HTML `->` browser receives response/HTML `->` browser parses HTML / executes JS. Just have a look at the document source in the browser, there is no PHP in there because it was already executed (on the server).

Comment: Known as the [Client-Server Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model)

Comment: @FelixKling:- You can post this as an answer rather than comment. I will surely upvote!

Comment: I feel like there needs to be a community wiki question and answer addressing this problem that we can palm these questions off to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP is executed on the server side, JavaScript on the client side.

The way it works is like this:

1. browser makes request
2. server receives request
3. server executes PHP
4. server sends response/HTML
5. browser receives response/HTML
6. browser parses HTML / executes JS.

Just have a look at the document source in the browser, there is no PHP in there because it was already executed (on the server).

---

What you can do instead is inject the value of the PHP variable into the JavaScript source code and manipulate the value with JavaScript:

```
var wow = <?php echo $wow; ?>
for(var i =0; i < 4; i++){
  alert(wow);
  wow++;
}
```

See also

- [Pass a PHP string to a JavaScript variable (and escape newlines)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/168214/218196)
- [How to access PHP variables in JavaScript or jQuery rather than <?php echo $variable ?>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1808108/218196)

Answer (score 0):

how about this one:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
<?php
    $wow = 0;
    while($wow < 4){
        echo "alert('" . $wow++ . "')";
    }
?>
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

php script is executed server side as per @Felix Kling comment..

dont define variable in php as php script executed server side not client side like javscript

u need to change script like ..

```
var wow = <?php echo $wow; ?>

for(var i =0; i < 4; i++){
   alert("<?php echo wow; ?>");
    <?php echo wow++; ?>
    }
```

but there is no meaning to use/create variable via php script

you can just simply write like this

```
var wow = <?php echo $wow; ?>
    for(var i =0; i < 4; i++){
       alert(wow);
       wow++;
        }
```