# Using nested JS functions with AJAX and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

OK so I am trying this whole AJAX thing and I hope I am doing this correctly. 
Here's the code:

```
function checkDate(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("dateMessage").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("dateMessage").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","scripts/checkDate.php?date="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();

        }
    }
    function registerBTN(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("register").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("register").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            var enableBTN = <?php echo $_SESSION["date"] ?>
            if (enableBTN) {
                $("register").removeAttr("disabled");
            }else{
                $("register").attr("disabled", "disabled");
            }
        }
    }
```

So the PHP calls `checkDate()` just fine and it works.

Here's what I (think) I want to do.

1) In `checkDate()` just after the `xmlhttp.send()` I want to call `registerBTN`. I am not sure how to do that.

2) I cannot confirm if `registerBTN` works at all. It should enable or disable based on the PHP session variable which is controlled in `checkDate.php`

Please let me know if you need any further information from me.

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: this: `var enableBTN = <?php echo $_SESSION["date"] ?>` looks very suspicious. Check console for errors

Comment: why not just echo an attribute in PHP inside the markup. add disabled when not set.

Comment: I got the echo statement from: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808108/how-to-access-php-variables-in-javascript-or-jquery-rather-than-php-echo-vari

Comment: @Ghost I get that, but how do I make that dynamic based on the result from checkDate ?

Comment: @KeeganS what does the `registerBTN` supposed to do anyways? there is not enough context to go on, should it be working side by side with `checkDate()`? why not do them in the same request?

Comment: @Ghost registerBTN adds or removes the disable attribute based on the $_Session variable which checkDate sets in the referenced php file.