# Javascript/JQuery replace a div with content with a URL

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress

I'm using WordPress and trying to replace the content of a div using JQuery - that bit works.
However the content has a URL in it and it isn't working and I cannot see why.

I'm generating a variable in PHP:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'news' ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    // The Loop
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $news_item = '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
        $news_item .= get_the_excerpt();    
        $news_item .= "<BR>";
        $news_item .= "<a href=";
        $news_item .= get_permalink();
        $news_item .= ">";      
        $news_item .= "Read More...</a>";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

That bit works.

I'm putting that into a jQuery variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<?php  
    echo "var newsItem = '{$news_item}';";
?>

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#soap-frontpagenews').fadeOut(500, function() {
        jQuery(this).replaceWith(newsItem).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

and that bit works.  However the resultant HTML code is not right in the way it fails to produce the link correctly:

```
<h1>News</h1>
<h2>Taking Better Photos With Your Nikon</h2>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque fermentum ac urna et auctor. at…
<br>
<a href="http://212.159.165.84/~soapwp/2013/09/29/taking-better-photos-with-your-nikon"></a>
Read More...
```

in that Read More... is OUTSIDE the link tags.

Where am I going wrong please?

Best Regards

Dave

Comment: please add site url???

Comment: The `href` content (url) must be in quotes: `"<a href='"` ... `"'>"`

Comment: Try this too: `echo "var newsItem = \`{$news_item}\`";`

Comment: I had tried the quotes but it was then failing completely - thanks for responding though ppasler.

Javascript needs the ;  mplungjan

Comment: Look again. My quotes are backticks - you still need quotes but you will have trouble with wrapping single quotes in double quotes and vice versa. Hence the JSON encode was a better idea. Still backticks is also a solution

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :**

Your string is breaking because missing a single quote.You need to wrap up url into a single quoted string.

**So Your code is something like this:**

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'news' ) );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    // The Loop
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        $news_item = '<h2>' . get_the_title() . '</h2>';
        $news_item .= get_the_excerpt();    
        $news_item .= "<BR>";
        $news_item .= "<a href='";
        $news_item .= get_permalink();
        $news_item .= "'>";      
        $news_item .= "Read More...</a>";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

**Javascript Code  (Updated Code)**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var newsItem = "<?php echo $news_item; ?>"; // Variable assignment 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#soap-frontpagenews').fadeOut(500, function() {
        jQuery(this).replaceWith(newsItem).fadeIn(500);
    });
});
</script>
```

Update :

variable should be quoted `var newsItem = "<?php echo $news_item; ?>";`

Comment: Already answered in the comment. Really not worth an answer, rather a close as typo

Comment: Just check it again,I have updated js code and php code both.comment add while typing answer

Comment: why??Its not valid?

Comment: Since when is an unquoted string valid JavaScript?

Comment: when we assign value to textbox.value=<?php echo $a;?>

Comment: textbox.value=<h2>....</h2> is not valid JS - if $a contains a quotes string it will work

Comment: @mplungjan thanks I am not aware about it.It break JS in google chrome

Comment: It breaks JS in all JavaScript implementations

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal

Comment: Your update will fail since your $news_item has single quotes too

Comment: Your update will fail if your $news_item has double quotes too - for example `$news_item .= "<a href=\"";
        $news_item .= get_permalink();
        $news_item .= "\">";`

Comment: that's reason I have used single qoute

Comment: You cannot rely on this.If get_the_excerpt() or get_the_title() has single or double quotes it will fail

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a PHP variable to a Javasript variable, it is better to use [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.json-encode.php):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
<?php  
    echo "var newsItem = " . json_encode( $news_item ) . ";";
?>
```

---

**But I would do it in another way:** You can put all the news items directly from PHP in HTML div container with `display: none` and manage the news rotation with jQuery then.

Comment: there is nothing like a json

Comment: Its simple variable value

Comment: `$news_item` contains many unknown content, single quotes, double qoutes and maybe other special chars, that certainly is not valid.

Comment: I'm not sure if it must be quoted -> [look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1808108/how-to-access-php-variables-in-javascript-or-jquery-rather-than-php-echo-vari#answer-1808161)

Comment: If it is JSON_Encoded it should not be quoted, but then you want to decode it before inserting it

Comment: Spot on Andy Tschiersch, many thanks. The json_encode worked.